# Стоит ли учить язык Python в 2021?

Tags: python

Мой первый язык это Python, изучаю язык 3-4 месяца(мой 1 язык программирования) и недавно узнал новость про то, что больше новых версий не будет, в связи с этим , стоить углубляться в него дальше?
Новость узнал на официальном сайте Python: https://www.python.org

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Мне жаль, но скорее всего, Ваш вопрос закроют как "вопрос, на котрый нельзя дать объективный ответ"

Тем не менее, я хочу привести вам всего несколько фактов, котоорые позволят Вам самому сделать вывод.

Во первых, "новых версий не будет" означает, что переход со второго питона на третий решил все структурые проблемы, и дальнейшее развитие языка возможно без "глобальной поломки мира" (которой, в какой то степени, и является такая большая смена версии)

Заметим, что этот переход (когда одновременно существовали и поддерживались оба - второй и третий - питоны) занял десять лет. Десять!

Во вторых, в языках программирования не настолько большую роль играет "внутренность" языка (его синтаксис и т.п.), как его "внешность" - то есть, набор и наличие библиотек, которые решают разные задачи, и самое главное - существующая вокруг этого языка культура. То есть, комьюнити, конференции, форумы, книги, общепринятые приёмы и отношение к тому, каким рекомендуется быть коду на этом языке.

А вот с этим - у Питона всё в порядке. Он прямо кросавчег!

Ну, и еще - как вам факт? По исследованиям не-британских ученых Питон является "языком номер два" (по популярности) почти для любой предметной области программирования, где он вообще применим. Для некотрых областей он является первым. Но вторым - почти всегда. Таким образом, это такой "запасной швейцарский нож" для очень многих задач.

Вообще, субъективно говоря, Питон играет роль такого "универсального клея", которым можно связать в один pipeline различные штуки.

Ну, и под завязку. Вы сами пишете, что это Ваш первый язык. Представтье себе, что Вы учитесь водить машину. И используете для этого какую то марку автомобиля. Но вы же, научившись, не собираетесь потом всю жизнь ездить только на машинах этой марки?

Это я намекаю на то, что сейчас весьма часто программист учит после первого языка какой то второй, и иногда не останавливается на этом :-)

Comment: Вот прям плюсую!

Comment: Спасибо огромное, моя первая мысль, увидев эту новость была: "И что теперь такой чудесный язык умрёт? ". Теперь понимаю, что это далеко не так, и он будет жить, всё таки не просто так он держится в топах. Он простой в изучении и я хочу его учить. По поводу закрытия опроса я приношу извинения, поспешил и не прочитал подробно правила , удалять опрос не рекомендуется поэтому пусть будет. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: И Вам спасибо за возможность порассуждать на близкие темы :-)

Comment: Этот ответ можно копипастить в введение книги "Питон для начинающих".